# scrumptious tutorial, open graph type error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm following the scrumptious tutorial (Android, but it's unrelated), I'm stuck at the last step to publish to the open graph. 
I've defined my custom object (Pizza) [here](https://tungscrumptious.herokuapp.com/pizza.html). I've tested it on the Object debugger, and everything ok. The tested result shows:

```
Scrape Information

Response Code:  206
Fetched URL:    https://tungscrumptious.herokuapp.com/pizza.html

Canonical URL:  https://tungscrumptious.herokuapp.com/pizza.html
Object Properties

fb:app_id:  106093806983
og:url: https://tungscrumptious.herokuapp.com/pizza.html
og:type:    tungscrumptious:meal
og:title:   Pizza
og:image:   
og:updated_time:    1377354274
Raw Open Graph Document Information

Meta Tag:   <meta property="fb:app_id" content="106093806983" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:type" content="tungscrumptious:meal" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:url" content="https://tungscrumptious.herokuapp.com/pizza.html" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:title" content="Pizza" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:image" content="https://tungscrumptious.herokuapp.com/pizza.jpg" />
URLs

Graph API:  https://graph.facebook.com/510362212378653
Scraped URL:     See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL
```

However, when I try to post to the graph as in the photo below: 
[image]

I got the error:
 "message": "(#3502) Object at URL https://graph.facebook.com/510362212378653 has og:type of 'website'. The property 'meal' requires an object of og:type 'tungscrumptious:meal'. "

Clearly, the `og:type` as shown by the debugger is `tungscrumptious:meal`, `not website`. Any idea what else to check? Tks

Answer (score 0):

try to put the endpoint url of the meal object : `https://tungscrumptious.herokuapp.com/pizza.html`

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason for the error: I had changed the name of the app on herokuapp.com from the default id (storm9xxxx.herkuapp.com) to tungscrumptious.herokuapp.com but didn't remove the old name from the field `domain` in the app settings on Fb.
Hope it helps someone.